# Understanding the method of obtaining an expression for the $p$-value using a test with test statistic $T =\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \theta_0)/\sigma$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

We are in a setting where we $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim N(\theta, \sigma^2)$ where we assume $\sigma^2$ to be known. We test $H_{0}:\theta\leq\theta_{0}$ versus $H_{1}:\theta>\theta_{0}$.

I am aware that this question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617458/derive-an-expression-for-the-p-value-using-a-test-with-test-statistic-t-sqr) but my teacher gave me a different way of obtaining the answer. However, I am not sure how exactly this method works so I'd like some additional explanation.

**The answer my teacher gave:** We know that our test statistic $T$ follows a standard normal distribution. Therefore, the $p$-value can be derived from:

> $p=\sup_{\theta\leq\theta_{0}}\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(T>t)=\mathbb{P}_{\theta_{0}}(T>t)=1-\Phi(\sqrt{n}\frac{(\bar{X}_n - \theta_0)}{\sigma})$

Where $t$ is some realization from the test statistic.

**My problem:** Perhaps some notation is incorrect because it was just a quick scribble made by him. However, there must be some truth behind this way of obtaining the $p$-value. My question is, why does this work? What is necessary for this to work, other than $T$ being standard normally distributed?

Any additional information helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, the supremum can be done away with since the probability clearly achieves its largest value for $\theta_0$. This is because it's an upper tail probability, and so the value of $\theta$ (the location parameter) that will make it largest is the value of theta most to the right (that is, largest) if that makes sense. In general, it is not always the case that the supremum can be collapsed like this into the highest value.

Comment: @Xiaomi Thanks for the tip. I'm confused though. Wouldn't it make more sense if the probability was higher for a smaller $\theta$? As I'm seeing it, the value of the test statistic increases as $\theta$ decreases (because we subtract $\theta$ in the numerator), i.e. the value of $T$ increases and thus there is a greater probability of this value laying above $t$. Where is the flaw in this reasoning? Edit: Or is it because T in this case doesn't even contain $\theta$ as a variable but just contains $\theta_{0}$?

Comment: If the true $\theta$ is smaller, then since you're subtracting $\theta_0$, you're "over correcting" and as a result $T$ will no longer be zero mean (standard normal). Instead, it will have mean $\theta-\theta_0 < 0$. Hence, since the mean of $T$ is below zero, upper tail probabilities will be reduced. This is assuming the test statistic only depends on $\theta_0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Xiaomi That does make sense, thank you. So if I understand correctly then in the other case where the true $\theta$ would be larger, we would be under correcting by subtracting $\theta_{0}$. However, this is not possible because we are maximizing the probability under the assumption that $H_{0}$ is true, i.e. $\theta < \theta_{0}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. We're only maximizing over $\theta < \theta_0$.